# Dynamically update key in mongoose

Tags: node.js

So i want to be able to update my mongoDB database dynamically and for some reason i am not being able to set the value to the key from the req.body that i get.

The code below shows Find() and not Update() but i will change it when i figure out how to set value dynamically

```
  app.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), (req, res, err) => {

    if (req.file) {

    var query = {};

    query["index"] = req.body.imageindex;

    Image.find(query, function(err, found){
        console.log(found);
    })
};
res.redirect("/")
```

Now if i would change the "req.body.imageindex" to simply 1(not a string) then it works and it returns a object in the console.log(found), but not when i have the req.body.index. Any way aroudn this or reason why?

});

UPDATE: it now works by using this code:

```
   if (req.file) {

    var index = JSON.parse(req.body.imageindex, null, ' ')
    var query = {index: index};
    console.log();

    Image.find(query, function(err, found){
        console.log(found);

    })
};
res.redirect("/")
```

Comment: is req.body.imageindex defined? What do you see if you add console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, ' '))

Comment: i get the object from req.body which i want so it works from doing what you said, but it does not find anything in the "found";

Comment: Okay it works now, i took the JSON.stringify you said and changed it to JSON.parse and now i find the result! Thank you